# Prevent angular transpiler from stripping `debugger` statements

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on an angular/typescript package and running it locally with `ng serve`. The problem is, I think the transpiler must be using some production settings or something because the resulting js has all of the `debugger` statements stripped out, as well as some other changes such as converting variable names to single letters, simplifying logic structures, etc.

How do I disable this? Is it a setting in `tsconfig`?

Comment: By default the compiler doesn't remove the debugger statement. Do you have some kind of custome config ?  Do you see them in the map files ? in the js files ?

Comment: I assume I do have some custom config somewhere, but I don't know where I would find it, or what setting I'm looking for. In the final main.js file they are gone

Comment: Are you using a dev config or a prod config ?

Comment: So, I was using a custom config, and it turned out to be missing the setting `"optimization": false`. I added that setting in and now it's working as expected

Comment: having `optimization:true` makes it in fact a prod config yes !

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem. I was using a custom config instead of the default development config. In my `angular.json` file I added

`"optimization": false`

to my custom config. I guess this is `true` by default and strips debugger statements etc.